# Self-hosted SignalR Windows services listening on different ports with the same IP

Tags: c#, signalr

I am currently using a self-hosted SignalR Windows service on a staging environment. Everything works well, that's why I now would like to set up a production environment.

I thought I'd only have to choose another port for my second Windows service, but I have never succeeded. The service launches well, but I am unable to contact it. Every call gets an error 500.

The error message tells :

> An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details.  ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException (0x80004005): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Has anyone ever got this error while setting up a second SignalR service ?

I need to use the same IP address because I only own one server.

Thanks a lot.

Olivier

Comment: "Please see the innerException"... You should probably post the contents of the inner exception here as well

Comment: Thank you FishySwede for your answer. Unfortunately, I can't find any inner exception. :(

Comment: Using HttpListener in production is not recommended. Why don't you just use IIS?

Comment: Thanks Pawel for your answer. Could you explain me why self-hosted SignalR service is not recommanded ?